# c# Form Designer - generated code problem

Tags: c#, form-designer, overriding

I have map control on main form. Problem is, when form designer generate code then **overrides value of variable** (RouteOverlay and MarkerOverlay) with new value and i don't want that.

Before generated code

```
//Map.cs
RouteOverlay = new GMapOverlay(this, "routes");
MarkerOverlay = new GMapOverlay(this, "markers");
```

After generated code

```
//MainForm.designer.cs
this.map1.MarkerOverlay = ((GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapOverlay)(resources.GetObject("map1.MarkerOverlay")));
this.map1.RouteOverlay = ((GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapOverlay)(resources.GetObject("map1.RouteOverlay")));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `[DesignerSerializationVisiblity(DesignerSerializationVisiblity.Hidden)]` to the properties.
This will completely prevent the designer from saving them.

Comment: Note that any changes you make in the designer will not be saved.  Consider adding `[Browsable(false)]`

Comment: And if you should want to be able to decide whether to serialize a property or not (e.g. you want to serialize it only when the value is different from the default one), just add a method named ShouldSerializeMarkerOverlay returning true when the property has to be serialized, and false otherwise.